# Conditional "WHEN" sentence in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure that generates a log of phone calls. As default it just outputs calls from all numbers, but I would like to add a @Number variable,

```
 where - if not null - it should add "WHERE number = @Number"...
```

I already have a lot of WHEN clauses in the SP, so this would be an additional one that comes in if the `@Number` isn't null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done with an OR expression:

```
Where (@Number Is Null OR number = @Number)
```